# how to center equations in parentheses

Tags: equations

this is what I have:

```
\begin{equation}
p(0) = C_h + \left(
\begin{split}
R_h \ cos \ \psi_h\\
R_h \ sin \ \psi_h \\
0 
\end{split}
\right)
\end{equation}
```

[image: equation]

wondering how I can obtain this:[image: equation1]

thanks much

Comment: `\cos`  not `\ cos`  then use `\begin{pmatrix}` not `split`

Answer (score 5):

As `DavidCarlisle` suggested, I would use the `pmatrix` environment of the `amsmath` package.

Your example can be translated into this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
p(0) = C_h + 
\begin{pmatrix}
R_{h}\cos\psi_{h}\\
R_{h}\sin\psi_{h}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

with the following result:

[image]

Please mind that:

- I've rewritten the correct math operators `\sin` and `\cos`
- I've removed the extra spaces `\␣` you had inserted, since the correct operators will handle the spaces well

In case you want what you've inserted (very small) below (i.e. with bold math symbols) you should use the `\mathbf` command, as shown below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{p}(0) = \mathbf{c}_h + 
\begin{pmatrix}
R_{h}\cos\psi_{h}\\
R_{h}\sin\psi_{h}\\
0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

**Not recommending this last part, included just for completeness sake**

Finally, if you want your matrix to be typeset in text, and obtain the smaller matrix you posted (assuming the scaling is correct), you should use `\psmallmatrix`, provided by the `mathtools` package as such:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \begin{document}
 test text, $\mathbf{r}(0) = \mathbf{c}_h + 
 \begin{psmallmatrix}
 R_{h}\cos\psi_{h}\\
 R_{h}\sin\psi_{h}\\
 0
 \end{psmallmatrix}$
 \end{document}
```

(corrected as suggested by @daleif) with result:

[image]

Please mind that, in this case, the composition is kind of typographically ugly, since the matrix is big, and is likely to produce an asymmetry with other lines in the text flow, yielding an ugly, less legible result. **Hence I don't recommend this last approach.**

Comment: Btw mathtools provides a psmallmatrix env, saves a bit of typing. +1 for a good explanation

Comment: @daleif corrected with your remark. Cheers.